# What's wrong the this jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery.fn.func = function()
{
    this.each(function(){
        $(this).onclick(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
}

$('#id1,#id2').func();
```

It reports:

```
$(this).onclick is not a function.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You're probably looking for `click()` instead of `onclick()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not define a method called `onclick` - it is `click`.

```
 $(this).click(function()
 {
     // Do Stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `onclick` with `click`

You will find the documentation of this event method on a dedicated [jQuery doc page](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

> **`.click( handler(eventObject) )`**
>
> Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element

Answer (score 1):

The right way is:

```
$(this).click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.click` instead of `.onclick`.